# Is it possible to re-watch recent matches?

Tags: battlefield-3

I was beasting on BF3 and there is this one match that I want to watch again.

Comment: I assume you mean like the way the Halo games do it?  Where you can go back and view a recorded replay of your past few games?

Comment: @user29484 - did the answer satisfy your question? If so, please accept

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately Battlefield 3 does not have a theater mode. The only way to re-watch them would be if you recorded while playing, such as using a HDMI capture box like the [Blackmagic Intensity](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/) on a console, or using a screen capture program like [Bandicam](http://www.bandicam.com/) or [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com) on a PC.

You can review the stats of your recent matches on [Battlelog](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/), but this will only show essentially most of the stats that appear at the match summary screen after a match.

Recently, EA announced the release of Battlefield 4 for sometime late in October 2013, which will include a theater mode.